# Glass Mapper Caching Value?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, glass-mapper, sitecore-mvc

Using Sitecore 8.0u3 and Glass-Mapper 3.5.3

I've run into an interesting situation that I can't resolve.  I'm seeing on certain controller renderings that some values for simple text fields(single-line, multiline) appear to be cached.  Other controller renderings do not appear to have this issue.

I attempt to write out the intro text for the form like so:

```
<div class="intro">@Editable(m => Model.ContextItem.Intro_Text)</div>
<div>RAW: @Model.ContextItem.Intro_Text</div>
```

Note that the second line was added by me for troubleshooting purposes.

In this case, the result of this is:

> Fill out the form to contact uss.
>
> RAW: Fill out the form to contact uss.

I update the text in Sitecore to remove the extra 's', save and publish.  I refresh my page and I see this:

> Fill out the form to contact uss.
>
> RAW: Fill out the form to contact us.

So the portion that does not use `Editable` works fine, but the `Editable` version continues to show the 'old' value.

I've looked at a lot of settings including the cacheability of the rendering, the cacheability of the site, the `Caching.Enabled` setting, the `Caching.HTMLLifetime` setting, IIS caching, publishing restrictions, but none seem to affect this issue.

Any ideas of other places to look for the source of the issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need to use the syntax `<div class="intro">@Editable(m => m.ContextItem.Intro_Text)</div>` rather than `<div class="intro">@Editable(m => Model.ContextItem.Intro_Text)</div>`

Comment: Yes the syntax works it just does not show the latest values from Sitecore unless you recycle the app pool. That was my experience using Sitecore 8  and Glass 4

Comment: Yeah spoke on sitecore slack looks like the lambada is cached and glass guys recommend using the syntax you've suggested.

Comment: Nice!  Changed the syntax to be consistent. (m/m vs m/Model)  Works great now!  Perhaps might work the same as @jwsadler suggested when using Model/Model.

Comment: Great! That took some time to figure out a rendering issue!

Answer (score 1):

I cam across this issue a while ago.  Change the syntax to be @Editable(Model => Model.ContextItem.Intro_Text)

Answer (score 0):

The @Editable() looks at the HtmlString and most probably displays it from the HtmlCache. I have seen this issue as well and during build process and I have to do re-publish all to clear caches, specially when I will be making data template changes.

You can try few things in your development environment and narrow down the issue.

1. Once you make a change, clear HTML cache from /sitecore/admin/cache.aspx and check the page again.
2. Try doing an incremental publish to the site as it will clear HTML cache.
3. Try doing a republishing the site.

Also, disable the output cache for the website under